# how to do suggestionCallback in typeahead flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-typeahead

i'm beginner in flutter, in my flutter project i used flutter_typeahead  package but i did not able to execute this code.

i did not get proper guidance from this documentation https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_typeahead/latest/flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead-library.html

```
    suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
      return CitiesService.getSuggestions(pattern);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example service is here, pattern in CitiesService example means contain some characters

https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead/blob/master/example/lib/data.dart

```
import 'dart:math';

class BackendService {
  static Future<List> getSuggestions(String query) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    return List.generate(3, (index) {
      return {'name': query + index.toString(), 'price': Random().nextInt(100)};
    });
  }
}

class CitiesService {
  static final List<String> cities = [
    'Beirut',
    'Damascus',
    'San Fransisco',
    'Rome',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Madrid',
    'Bali',
    'Barcelona',
    'Paris',
    'Bucharest',
    'New York City',
    'Philadelphia',
    'Sydney',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = List();
    matches.addAll(cities);

    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}
```

Comment: if it solve your problem. please mark this as answer. if not solve your problem please tell me further error message. thanks.

Comment: brilliant answer! Now I need to figure out how to use an API with it :(